# False 302 redirect instead of 200 on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, seo, http-status-code-302

On my website I have 3000 pages with 302 answer instead of 200, Google is dumping all my pages, products, articles, everything. It's a SEO nightmare.
Some few page answer with 200, no apparent reason.
What it can be the reason?

Example pages : https://www.musclenutrition.com/about-us
Page is visualized correctly, but seems redirected to the home page. Cookies are weird.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
>>> https://www.musclenutrition.com/about-us

> --------------------------------------------
> 302 Found
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 302 Found
Code: 302
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 12 Nov 2016 22:52:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.10
Set-Cookie: frontend_cid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=.www.musclenutrition.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://www.musclenutrition.com/
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN




>>> https://www.musclenutrition.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 200 OK
Code: 200
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 12 Nov 2016 22:52:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.10
Set-Cookie: frontend_cid=SrDTfwPSAoHwK3iO; expires=Sun, 13-Nov-2016 07:52:56 GMT; Max-Age=32400; path=/; domain=.www.musclenutrition.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Pragma: no-cache
Fpc-Cache-Id: FPC_REQUEST_83ac81f64442a0c9f406d1ba2acde4ed
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: Could you share your nginx configuration?

Comment: I'm trying to insert the configuration, but i seems I can't write more then 300 chars

Comment: I believe is one of these files you are interested in :  # For user configurations not maintained by DirectAdmin. Empty by default.
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-includes.conf;

    # Supplemental configuration
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-modsecurity-enable.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-defaults.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-gzip.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-ips.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-settings.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-vhosts.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/directadmin-vhosts.conf;

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a way to answer properly with a decent formatted text.

Comment: That file doesn't include anything related redirecting, after taking a look at the error again, it doesn't seem to be a redirect caused by nginx, as that would mean it never called the php processor. The bug is probably caused inside the php code

Comment: Ok, I found the config file, but I have no idea on how to show, I'm limited to very short answer. I found some redirect 301, probably from the http - https, but no 302. What do you think it can be to redirect this way? It's a Magento website.

Comment: You could try inspecting the places the following Stack Exchange question shows: [302 redirect issues. Page header shows 302 for all pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111320/302-redirect-issues-page-header-shows-302-for-all-pages) FYI: You could always [edit] your question to include more information

Comment: Thank you Ferry :)